# Add Property to Object Array From Other Array - JS

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to add a property to an array of objects from another existing array (both from the same length)

Example:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [{word: "hey"}, {word: "hello"}, {word: "world"}]

//Wanted Outcome: array2 = [{word: "hey", id: 1}, {word: "hello", id: 2}, {word: "world", id: 3}]
```

What I've tried:

```
for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
    for(var j= 0; j<array2.length; j++){
       array2[j].id = array1[i];
  }
}
//Outcome Im getting: array2 = [{word: "hey", id: 3}, {word: "hello", id: 3}, {word: "world", id: 3}]
```

How can I add a different property based on the first array length to the second array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop here. Just you one level for loop and use `i` as both the indices

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [{word: "hey"}, {word: "hello"}, {word: "world"}]
for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
  array2[i].id = array1[i];
}
console.log(array2);
```

Cleaner way for doing this is to use `map()`

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [{word: "hey"}, {word: "hello"}, {word: "world"}]
array2 = array2.map((x, i) => ({...x, id: array1[i]}));
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need

```
array2.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.id = array1[i]
})
```